# Anki + Latex not working : I have installed BasicTex + dvipng

Tags: latex

I'm trying to get Anki to work with Latex. Currently, when I open a flashcard with latex on it I get:
`Generated file: /var/folders/41/v5plvhx12wg0qlrj9h_l0g680000gn/T/anki_temp/tmp.tex
Have you installed latex and dvipng?`

However, I have already installed BasicTex + dvipng. In fact, when I run `which latex` and `which dvipng` on terminal I get:
`/Library/TeX/texbin/latex` and `/Library/TeX/texbin/dvipng`.

So I need some help. Would anyone know how to make Anki work with Latex? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Thanks for asking and answering! If you want to help others, consider editing in your OS X version and the versions to the tools you have installed. That really helps people that just need to update things and pins down old posts so that we know when things change or break (again) should they do just that.

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer here [Anki+Latex](http://www.jasoncantarella.com/wordpress/anki-2-022latexmavericks-problems-and-solutions/).

Basically you have to download [this Anki add-on](https://ankiweb.net/shared/info/937148547), which allows you to edit the path Anki uses to find latex and dvipng. Then you use `which latex` and `which dvipng` (on Mac terminal) to get the full path to each of them, and then you use the add-on to modify Anki's path.

Comment: Hello, I am in the exact same boat for this question. I have downloaded the add-on but am stuck at that point. When I use \which\ in the terminal, it cannot find TeX or dvipng, even though I see them in the finder. Once I have the path, how do I edit the extension to modify Anki's path? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: @cdarwin If you can see it through finder then you have the path (maybe you're typing which in a weird way and it's not working). Now to modify the path in Anki you need to download an Anki plugin called "Edit LaTeX build process"; (just google it and you will find it), it allows you to modify the path to latex, so you just add the path you found there. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Updated for 2020: You can find LaTeX installation instructions in the Anki User Manual [here](https://apps.ankiweb.net/docs/manual.html#latex-support).

> To install LaTeX, on Windows use MiKTeX; on OSX use MacTex, and on Linux use your distro’s package manager. Dvipng must also be installed.

For example, on Mac you can run `brew install --cask mactex` and that should be all you need to get it working with Anki. I had the same error as you, and this process fixed it for me.

You can then use Anki's **Tools > Check Media...** to generate all LaTeX images and sync them to AnkiWeb in order to use them on mobile devices.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem because I had copied in an apostrophe that LaTeX didn't like. You might want to try checking your LaTeX compiles elsewhere first.